# Optimization on preseed debian-installer testing

Tags: preseed, debian-installer

Alright I am struggling with preseed because the whole process takes so much time for changing preseed then testing it (VM's are too slow and to test on the same machine I have to isolate all other HDD to prevent any mess).

What could I do in order to optimize preseed configuration on debian-installer?

Is there any tool in order to quickly validate my seed files to my desire?